# How to make this vue component reusable with it's props?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to make this component reusable so later can install it in any project and via props add needed values e.g. images and function parameters (next, prev, intervals...) inside any component.

```html
        <template>
        <div>
            <transition-group name='fade' tag='div'>
              <div v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key='i'>
                <img :src="currentImg" />
              </div>
            </transition-group>
            <a class="prev" @click="prev" href='#'>&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" @click="next" href='#'>&#10095;</a>
          </div>
        </template>

        <script>
        export default {
          name: 'Slider',
          data() {
            return {
              images: [
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/12/15/24/amsterdam-1089646_1280.jpg',
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/17/23/03/usa-1206240_1280.jpg',
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/27/eiffel-tower-768501_1280.jpg',
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/04/19/30/berlin-cathedral-1882397_1280.jpg'
                ],
              timer: null,
              currentIndex: 0,
            }
          },

            mounted: function() {
              this.startSlide();
            },

            methods: {
              startSlide: function() {
                this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 4000);
              },


              next: function() {
                this.currentIndex += 1
              },
              prev: function() {
                this.currentIndex -= 1
              }
            },

            computed: {
              currentImg: function() {
                return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
              }
            }

        }
        </script>

    styles...
```

So later it would be `<Slider... all props, images loop here/>` inside other components.

How can be it be achieved?

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Just move what needs to come from another component to `props`. That way other component can pass the relevant info it needs.

```js
export default {
          name: 'Slider',
          props: {
              images: Array,
              next: Function
              prev: Function,
              // and so on
          },
...
```

The parent component would call it like:

```html
<Slider :images="imageArray" :next="nextFunc" :prev="prevFunc" />
```

### EDIT

You can pass an interval value via props:

```js
export default {
          name: 'Slider',
          props: { intervalVal: Number },
          methods: {
              startSlide: function() {
                this.timer = setInterval(this.next, this.intervalVal);
              },
          }
```

You can also pass function from parent to child via props.

```js
export default {
          name: 'Slider',
          props: { next: Function },
          methods: {
              someMethod: function() {
                this.next() // function from the parent
              },
          }
```

I don't really understand your use case 100% but these are possible options.

Comment: `nextFunc()`/`prevFunc()` would be evaluated immediately (and the functions themselves would not be passed) in your example. Did you mean to use callbacks?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can next and prev be both boolean and function? Maybe on that page, those buttons are not needed to implement in the other component. Also how can use interval here 
startSlide: function() {
                this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 4000);
              },

as a prop?

Comment: Oops nice catch @tony19 - should pass the methods without `()`

Comment: In terms of callback not sure. Those 2 ones are just needed if the user wants to add those buttons inside their components. That's why I asked for boolean.

Comment: @NewTechLover They cannot be both, but you could check if a function is defined. As for the interval, you could just pass a prop for the interval time, sure

Comment: @T.Short the ''nextfunc" part is confusing. In the above example, next contains logic in the core slider component. Then what's that nextfunc that you added in your example inside the new component? Also how can interval be used as a separate prop since its inside startSlide?

Comment: I added more examples to my post. The simple point is whatever you need in your child component that needs to be dynamic depending on the parent, make them props